# How to implement a category system

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-models, django-templates, django-forms

I want to implement a category structure that works with i18n. Since GAE has builtin `db.CategoryProperty`but it doesn't implement subcategories and it seems I'm using the category property as it were a list object with my models.

```
class Vehicles(GeoModel,search.SearchableModel): 
  title=db.StringProperty(verbose_name="title")#required
  category=db.CategoryProperty(choices('0','1','2','3','4',default='1',verbose_name="Category") 
...
```

Not all vehicles have a gearbox of type manual or automatic but cars certainly do. So I can either add another instance variable, `gearbox = ...` but since that would have no meanings for most instances should I avoid that implementation and do it with inheritance instead:

```
class Cars(Vehicles): 
  gearbox=db.CategoryProperty(choices('0','1','2','3','4',default='1',verbose_name="Gearbox"
  mileage=db.CategoryProperty(choices('0','1','2','3','4','5',default='1',verbose_name="Mileage"
  fuel=db.CategoryProperty(choices('0','1','2','3','4',default='1',verbose_name="Fuel"
```

Is the solution with inheritance preferable over just adding subcategories' instance variables as instance variables in the base class? Will recategorizing objects still work if I use inheritance? How can I implement the choices so that it iterates over categories with i18n? My template currently looks like:

```
{% load i18n %}
<select name="cg" id="cat" class="category"> 
<option value='' style='background-color:#dcdcc3' id='cat1' >-- {% trans "VEHICLES" %} --</option>
<option value='2'  {% ifequal "2" cg %} selected="selected" {% endifequal %} id='cat2' >{% trans "Cars" %}</option>
...
```

Does django have a more convenient solution for this? What other classes does app engine / django have that can achieve a working implementation? Should I do my choices like this instead:

```
 choices = [ (1, _('Vehicles')), (2, _('Cars')), (3, _('Bicycles')), (4, _('Motorcycles')) ]
 category=db.CategoryProperty(choices('0','1','2','3','4',default='1',verbose_name="Category")
```

Comment: I haven't used Django for a while so won't answer, but you might want to look at the [Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) or [PolyModel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass.html) classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CategoryProperty` is just a `StringProperty` with a semantic name: when it is serialized to XML it uses a different tag name. Nothing else is different, really.

Your last snippet should work, but why rely on integer indexes? It may be problematic if you change the order one day. You could use a dict instead:

```
choices = {
    'vehicles': _('Vehicles'),
    'cars': _('Cars'),
    'bicycles': _('Bicycles'),
    'motorcycles': _('Motorcycles')
}
category = db.CategoryProperty(choices=choices.keys(), default='cars',
                               verbose_name="Category")
```

Comment: Thank you moraes. Why rely on integer indexes? Well the `cg=4` is the way the URL query is that should select a category. having a data model with my own integer indexes seemed wrong and now I see how I can do it with i18n and avoid having a data model that relies on making my own set of integers.